# get the return value of success in Iron-Ajax after POST

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, polymer-2.x

I'm currently working the project using **Polymer** and I'd like to get the **return value of API** after **POST** using Iron-Ajax.

Here is my sample code,

```
var rs = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: apiUrl,
    data: _data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json'
});

rs.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ajax` is `asynchronous` by default,you need add `async:false` to make it `synchronous`

```
var rs = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: apiUrl,
    data: _data,
    async:false,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json'
});

var result = null;
rs.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert(data);
    result = data;
    }
});

//return result;//you can return value like this
```